# Unable to edit .xml file using batch script to replace last occurence of search item?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to replace following string in the xml file which is the last last entry, there are multiple entries

for

> keystoreFile

and

> keystorePass

my script here

for testing I try to change first string which is keystoreFile

```
@echo off

set DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=%CD%

set KEYSTORE_NAME=minus



echo.
set /p PASS=Enter your store password in order to update the server.xml config file#




setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search_string=./conf/server.keystore

set replacement_string=%DESTINATION_DIRECTORY%\%KEYSTORE_NAME%.keystore

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("server.xml") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo !line:%search_string%=%replacement_string%!
    endlocal
) >> help10008.xml
```

The output I get is messy,

**original**

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="./conf/server.keystore" keystorePass="adventnet" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="agentSSL" port="8555" scheme="https" secure="true" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

**expected**

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\ManageEngine\ADAudit Plus\conf\minus.keystore" keystorePass="adventnet" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="agentSSL" port="8555" scheme="https" secure="true" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

this is what I'm getting with my current script however, but it also add erroneous data e.g

`./conf/server.keystore=C:\Program Files\ManageEngine\ADAudit Plus\conf\minus.keystore`

in place of

`keystoreFile="./conf/server.keystore"`

from the original xml, which I don't want I want somehow to match only the last entry the which is xml tag as shown above.

you may view the two xml files named good and bad accordingly

link https://file.io/MaM1rJeGea3J

Comment: Works as expected for me. Please note : Missing terminal `"` on setting `search_string`. `replacement_string` is set to `…keystorePass="%PAS%"` - should be `%PASS%`.  `>> help10008.xml` will append to an existing file. `> help10008.xml` would create the file anew. `keystorePass="adventnet"` remains in the replacement line, after the new `keystorePass=` element

Comment: kindly check i forgot to update the code the PASS code was added extra, i don't want to use it now as I just want to replace the `keystorePass` kindly see the update

Comment: Now works for me as expected. Using the `set "var=value"` syntax is recommended to avoid problems with trailing spaces.

Comment: i set both search_string and replacement_string under the `"` as you mentioned, but on line 71 of the appended file i can see `./conf/server.keystore=C:\Program Files\ManageEngine\ADAudit Plus\conf\minus.keystore` which was there before making the change?

Comment: `set "search_string=./conf/server.keystore"`




`set "replacement_string=%DESTINATION_DIRECTORY%\%KEYSTORE_NAME%.keystore"`